# How do I make my listbox allow me to select more than one item

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

I need help to make my AdditionalStaffEmailListBox_SelectedIndexChanged allow me to select more than one item. Right now It is only allowing me to select one item.

```
private void AdditionalStaffEmailListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdditionalStaffEmailListBox = new ListBox();
    AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
    AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.BeginUpdate();

    //Loop through all items in the AdditionalStaffEmailListBox 
    for (int x = 0; x < AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        //AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
        if (AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.GetSelected(x) == true)
        {
        //Deselect all items that are selected
        AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.SetSelected(x, false);
        }
        else
        {
        //Select all items that are not selected
         AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.SetSelected(x, true);
        }
    }
    //Force the AdditionalStaffEmailListBox to scroll back to the top of the list
    AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.TopIndex = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Try taking a look at the `.SelectionMode` property- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `AdditionalStaffEmailListBox = new ListBox();` why would you create a new instance in the selectedindex changed event? You will end up with an empty listbox which has no connection to the one where you selected the items

Comment: When I remove this line of code, I am getting the following error in debug mode System.StackOverflowException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdditionalStaffEmailListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

Hold Ctrl and then click to select the ones you want.

Comment: I did change my code to what you suggested. It is still now allowing me to select more than one item. When I select one, the code in bug mode runs and when I select another item, the first one is unselected.

Comment: Each time the selection changes you are creating a new listbox, cancelling any previous selection. Put the line of code I suggested in Page_Load (or something and then delete the top two lines of your event handler.

Comment: I have done what you suggested and now I am good. Thanks for your help.